# Squid cache not starting in Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, cache, squid

I'm trying to start Squid (3.5.12) by the following command:

```
$ /etc/init.d/squid start

[ ok ] Starting squid (via systemctl): squid.service.
```

but only one line appears in `cache.log`, and nothing else:

```
2017/03/23 18:44:40| Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid/cache
```

I did run `squid -z`.

My `squid.conf` looks as shown below:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 8080
maximum_object_size 100 MB
cache_mem 512 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 128 MB
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid/cache 20000 16 256
cache_swap_low 96
cache_swap_high 97
forwarded_for transparent
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid/cache
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
dns_nameservers 192.168.1.1
cache_effective_user proxy
cache_effective_group proxy
```

Comment: If squid is running, stop it, then try running `/usr/sbin/squid3 -YC -f /etc/squid3/squid.conf` attempt to start it directly from a shell.  You might also add a `-d1` to print extra debugging information.  Look for errors and messages.  Fix whatever errors you find, or edit into your post any ones you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Current Ubuntu LTS (16.04) system services should be best managed via systemd which means in your case that to start, check status, stop squid you would use (respectively):

```
# systemctl start squid
# systemctl status squid
# systemctl stop squid
```

the service command is also still supported for backward System V compatibility, but it might disappear in the future. Running services by invoking directly

```
# /etc/init.d/servicename
```

is not supported/recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was not to use `/etc/init.d/squid start` .

`service squid restart` is working ok.

Don't know why line 2`017/03/23 18:44:40| Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid/cache` appeared in logs.